# Configure hibernate in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

I worked with hibernate in MyEclipse.

But I want to work in Eclipse, and I'm unable to configure the hibernate project in it.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this Easy and Quickest tutorial:

[Configure Hibernate](http://kaanmutlu.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/hibernate-installationsetup-on-eclipse-ide/)